# How do I add collision detection to my javascript game?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, here's the deal,  I have been building a little runner game in javascript that seems to be working ok(ish).  I have both my players able to move simultaneously and I have an object constructor building objects from an array that I have.  Those objects are also successfully moving the direction and speed that I want but I am having trouble designing collision detection for them.  I know javascript is rather wonky on this stuff and I built my game in a weird way so there's also that but I figure there has to be some way to add it.  Here is all of my code.  If anyone knows about this stuff can you explain what I can do?

```js
var obstacles;
var $char1 = $('#character1');
var $char2 = $('#character2');

var object = 
[{name: 'Jerry', width: '10px', height: '30px', position: 'absolute', left: '100%', bottom: '0px', background: 'green'},
{name: 'Tammy', width: '9px', height: '25px', position: 'absolute', left: '100%', bottom: '0px', background: 'yellow'},
{name: 'Mr. Meeseeks', width: '10px', height: '35px', position: 'absolute', left: '100%', bottom: '0px', background: 'blue'},
{name: 'Mr. Meeseeks', width: '10px', height: '35px', position: 'absolute', left: '100%', bottom: '0px', background: 'blue'},
{name: 'Mr. Meeseeks', width: '10px', height: '35px', position: 'absolute', left: '100%', bottom: '0px', background: 'blue'},
{name: 'Mr. Meeseeks', width: '10px', height: '35px', position: 'absolute', left: '100%', bottom: '0px', background: 'blue'},
{name: 'Mr. Meeseeks', width: '10px', height: '35px', position: 'absolute', left: '100%', bottom: '0px', background: 'blue'},
{name: 'Telepathic Spider', width: '40px', height: '15px', position: 'absolute', left: '100%', bottom: '0px', background: 'black'},
{name: 'Telepathic Spider', width: '40px', height: '15px', position: 'absolute', left: '100%', bottom: '0px', background: 'black'},
{name: 'Telepathic Spider', width: '40px', height: '15px', position: 'absolute', left: '100%', bottom: '0px', background: 'black'},
{name: 'Telepathic Spider', width: '40px', height: '15px', position: 'absolute', left: '100%', bottom: '0px', background: 'black'},
{name: 'Counciler Rick 1', width: '10px', height: '30px', position: 'absolute', left: '100%', bottom: '0px', background: 'white'},
{name: 'Counciler Rick 2', width: '10px', height: '30px', position: 'absolute', left: '100%', bottom: '0px', background: 'white'},
{name: 'Counciler Rick 3', width: '10px', height: '30px', position: 'absolute', left: '100%', bottom: '0px', background: 'white'},
{name: 'Counciler Rick 4', width: '10px', height: '30px', position: 'absolute', left: '100%', bottom: '0px', background: 'white'},
{name: 'Federation Police', width: '12px', height: '25px', position: 'absolute', left: '100%', bottom: '0px', background: 'green'},
{name: 'Federation Police', width: '12px', height: '25px', position: 'absolute', left: '100%', bottom: '0px', background: 'green'},
{name: 'Federation Police', width: '12px', height: '25px', position: 'absolute', left: '100%', bottom: '0px', background: 'green'},
{name: 'Federation Police', width: '12px', height: '25px', position: 'absolute', left: '100%', bottom: '0px', background: 'green'},
{name: 'Federation Police', width: '12px', height: '25px', position: 'absolute', left: '100%', bottom: '0px', background: 'green'},
{name: 'Snowball', width: '15px', height: '45px', position: 'absolute', left: '100%', bottom: '0px', background: 'green'},
{name: 'Jellybean King', width: '15px', height: '25px', position: 'absolute', left: '100%', bottom: '0px', background: 'green'},
{name: 'Abradolf Linkler', width: '10px', height: '30px', position: 'absolute', left: '100%', bottom: '0px', background: 'green'},
{name: 'Cousin Nicki', width: '10px', height: '30px', position: 'absolute', left: '100%', bottom: '0px', background: 'green'},
{name: 'Fart', width: '15px', height: '15px', position: 'absolute', left: '100%', bottom: '0px', background: 'green'},
{name: 'Fart', width: '10px', height: '30px', position: 'absolute', left: '100%', bottom: '0px', background: 'green'},
{name: 'Fart', width: '10px', height: '30px', position: 'absolute', left: '100%', bottom: '0px', background: 'green'},
{name: 'Fart', width: '10px', height: '30px', position: 'absolute', left: '100%', bottom: '0px', background: 'green'}, 
{name: 'Fart', width: '10px', height: '30px', position: 'absolute', left: '100%', bottom: '0px', background: 'green'}];


function jump($el){
  $el.animate({bottom: '+=10px'}, .5);
}

function fall($el){
  $el.animate({bottom: 0});
}




keys = [false, false, false, false, false, false];



$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log('hi')
  obstacles
  // obstacles = new component(10, 200, "green", 300, 120);

  $(document).on('keydown', function(ex){
    switch(ex.keyCode) {
      case 38:
        keys[1] = true; //LEFT
        break;
      case 37:
        keys[0] = true; //UP
        break;
      case 39:
        keys[2] = true; //RIGHT
        break;
      case 65:
        keys[3] = true;
        break;
      case 87:
        keys[4] = true;
        break;
      case 68:
        keys[5] = true;
        break;
    }
  })

  $(document).on('keyup', function(ex){
    switch(ex.keyCode) {
      case 38:
        keys[1] = false;
        console.log('bottom');
        $char1.finish().animate({bottom: '0px'});
        break;
      case 37:
        keys[0] = false;
        break;
      case 39:
        keys[2] = false;
        break;
      case 65:
        keys[3] = false;
        break;
      case 87:
        keys[4] = false;
        console.log('2bottom');
        $char2.finish().animate({bottom: '0px'});
        break;
      case 68:
        keys[5] = false;
        break;
    }

  })

  function checkKeys(e) {
  if(keys[1] || keys[0] || keys[2] || keys[3] || keys[4] || keys[5]) {
              
        if (keys[2]) {
          console.log('right')
          $char1.finish().animate({left: '+=5px'});
        }

        if (keys[0]) {
          console.log('left');
          $char1.finish().animate({left: '-=5px'});
        }
        if (keys[1]) {
          console.log('up');
          jump($char1);
        }
        if (keys[3]) {
          console.log('2left')
          $char2.finish().animate({left: '-=5px'})
        }
        if (keys[4]) {
          console.log('2up')
          jump($char2);
        }
        if (keys[5]) {
          console.log('2right')
          $char2.finish().animate({left: '+=5px'})
        }
    }
  }

  window.setInterval(checkKeys, 1000 / 60);
  if ($char1.bottom > '150px') {
    $char1.bottom = '150px';
  }



  function Enemy (name, width, height, background, position, left, bottom, move) {
    this.name = name;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.background = background;
    this.position = position;
    this.left = left;
    this.bottom = bottom;
    this.move = move;
  }

  Enemy.prototype.render = function() {

    $('#upperSky').append($('<div>').addClass('enemyObject')
      .css('width', this.width)
      .css('height', this.height).css('background', this.background).css('position', this.position).css('left', this.left).css('bottom', this.bottom));
  };

  var enemyArray = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
    var r = makeRandomNum(object.length);
    var myObject = new Enemy(object[r].name, object[r].width, object[r].height, object[r].background, object[r].position, object[r].left, object[r].bottom);
    enemyArray.push(myObject);
  };
  var intervalId;
  var paintEnemies = function(){
    if(!enemyArray.length) {
      clearInterval(intervalId)
    }

    enemyArray.pop().render();
  };
  intervalId = setInterval(paintEnemies, 2000)

  function makeRandomNum(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max)
  }

  function moveObjectLeft() {
    $('.enemyObject').finish().animate({left: '-=50px'})
  }

  walkInterval = setInterval(moveObjectLeft, 1000)

  // collision1();
  // function collision1() {
  //   if ($char1.position().left < $('.enemyObject').position().left + $('.enemyObject').width && $char1.left + $char1.width > $('.enemyObject').left && $char1.bottom < $('.enemyObject').bottom + $('.enemyObject').height && $char1.bottom + $char1.height > $('.enemyObject').bottom) {
  //     console.log('collision detected');
  //   }
  // }

  

})
```

```css
.container {
  border: 5px solid black;
  height: 400px;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#upperSky {
  height: 300px;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: rgb(26, 167, 203);
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}
#character1 {
  height: 30px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}

#character2 {
  height: 30px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}

#cloud1 {
  height: 30px;
  width: 60px;
  background: url(../images/cloud1.png);
  position: absolute;
  
}
/*  animation-duration: 15s;
  animation-name: character1;*/

/*@keyframes character1 {
  from {
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 5%;
  }
  to {
    margin-left: 100%;
    width: 5%;
  }
}*/

#topGround {
  height: 15px;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: rgb(76, 40, 25);
}
#midGround {
  height: 30px;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: rgb(90, 51, 11);
}
#lowGround {
  height: 55px;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: rgb(136, 86, 21);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <title>THE RICK AND MORTY SUPER SHOWDOWN THIIIIIIIIING!!!!!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="allBody">
      <div class="headings">
        <h1 class="h1" id="gameTitle">The RICK AND MORTY SUPER SHOWDOWN OF STUUUUUUUUFFFFFFF!!!!</h1>
        <h6 class="h6" id="gameSubTitle">Blitz n Chips is not legally responsible for any real world psychotic damages this game causes.</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="environment sky" id="background">
          <div class="environment sky" id="upperSky">
            <div class="environment sky clouds" id="cloud1"></div>
            <div class="environment sky clouds" id="cloud2"></div>
            <div class="environment sky clouds" id="cloud3"></div>
            <div class="objects foreground characters" id="character1"></div>
            <div class="objects foreground characters" id="character2"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="environment backgroundWorld">
            <div class="environment backgroundWorld mountains" id="mountain1"></div>
            <div class="environment backgroundWorld mountains" id="mountain2"></div>
            <div class="environment backgroundWorld mountains" id="mountain3"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="environment ground" id="topGround"></div>
        <div Class="environment ground" id="midGround"></div>
        <div Class="environment ground" id="lowGround"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="buttons gameButtons"
        <button class="buttons gameButtons" id="gameReturn">Return Home</button>
        <button class="buttons gameButtons" id="gamePlayGame">Play Game</button>
        <button class="buttons gameButtons" id="gameReset">Reset</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="./js/jquery.2.2.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/app.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Your question is a bit messy. I would get rid of a large part of the code you've provided, as it doesn't directly affect the answer. Collision detection is a broad subject, and something you should look into before asking. It would be best if you ask a SPECIFIC question about it, rather than "How do I implement it". Also, this is of course preference, but it will mostly likely be easier to manage collision detection if your project is build on HTML5 canvas, rather than elements. That will also help with optimization.

Comment: I am a student and have not actually ever dealt with canvasses before.  I decided to put this together as a small project and have most of the parts working but I cannot seem to get collision detection down.

Answer (score 1):

The most basic collision detection, the type where non-transformed rectangles collide consists of the following:

1. Objects that need to be checked for collision. For instance I could have an array of coins and a player character. What I want to be checked all the time is if the player is colliding with the coins. One of the most important parts of writing well performing collisions detection is figuring out what needs to interact with what.
2. A check to confirm that a collision has occurred. Like I mentioned, it's very simple to do with plain rectangle ( which is by the way, what most HTML elements are). So we can do something like this:

   var coins= [];
   var player= {};

Lets assume the coins array is filled with objects which have a x, y, width and height. The player object is similar in that regard.

```
// This function is called every frame, or less often if you want to optimize.
function checkCollisions() {
  for (var coinIdx= 0; coinIdx < coins.length; coinIdx++) {
    var coin = coins[coinIdx];

    if (coin.x < player.x + player.width &&
       coin.x + coin.width > player.x &&
       coin.y < player.y + player.height &&
       coin.height + coin.y > player.y) {
     console.log('COLLISION');
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: what is x?  I don't think I have an x variable.  Is it the same as .left?

Comment: Yes. In css terms x is left and y is top